# SonarQube with MsBuild: sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths no protobuf files will be loaded for this project

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am running the SonarQube 7.5 with Sonar Scanner MsBuild 4.5 and it works but no results is available on the project configured on the Sonar. Let me detail what I have done.

**What I have done**

I installed the SonarQube V7.5 Community and start it as a Windows Service. I download the MsBuild Scanner 4.5 and add this folder on the `PATH` of the Windows fallowing the documentation. After that, I create a new project and run the scripts on a Dummy Console Application. The scripts I have run over the console are:

Run the `BEGIN` step of the SonarQube

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin 
              /k:"HappyAppKey" 
              /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" 
              /d:sonar.login="f3965814e7fdcf4f32e26adc1e69d6f5f851cafc"
```

Run the MSBUILD to compile the project from the `sln` file

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe HappyApp.sln /t:Rebuild
```

Run the `END` step of the SonarQube to analysis and submit

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end 
           /d:sonar.login="f3965814e7fdcf4f32e26adc1e69d6f5f851cafc"
```

It works without errors and I can see the source code on the sonarQube but no bugs, smell code, duplications etc... are available to see on the SonarQube like the picture bellow

[image]

Analysing the generated log on the `end` step, I can see this warning message

```
15:24:48.807 WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
15:24:48.808 WARN: No Roslyn issues report found for this project.
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I add something on the folder of the project? Any file to configure something? (It's my first time with SonarQube).

Thank you.

Comment: Any warnings or errors found in the SonarQube log files?

Comment: @JeroenHeier, Yes, I updated the question. I can see the warning message `WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project. 
WARN: No Roslyn issues report found for this project.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Install the right `MsBuild` version (which should be 14 or above for .Net Framework projects). Follow these steps:

- Download and install the [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) available on this link
- Note that you now have the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`.
- Over the command prompt, navigate at the folder and perform a `MsBuild -version` and you should see the right version:

```
Microsoft(R) Build Engine versão 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 para .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

15.9.21.664
```

- If you want, add the folder on the `PATH` of the Windows.
- Build your project using this Msbuild.exe.

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"MyProjectKey" /d:sonar.verbose=true /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="3c8d70d998f72178c7a21c1a83590d8af1f6e014"

MSBuild.exe "D:\temp\MyProject\Project.csproj" /t:Rebuild 

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="3c8d70d998f72178c7a21c1a83590d8af1f6e014"
```

- Access the the SonarQube from http://localhost:9000 and you should see the result of the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. But I use the right version of MSBuild.

```
d:\build\workspace\walls_Build_wb11452\WBServices>d:\build\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\Scanner_for_MsBuild_4.6.2\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:project_name /n:project_name /v:"2" /d:sonar.language=cs /d:sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 /d:sonar.host.url="url" /d:sonar.login="******" 
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.6.2

d:\build\workspace\walls_Build_wb11452\WBServices>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" Solution.sln /t:Rebuild /m:2 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:DefineConstants="X64PROCESS;AUTO" 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
```

No idea...